# Можно ли сделать поле уникальным при наличии идентивикатора MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый день.
Пусть есть таблица vehicle (id), route (id). Каждое трансп. средство закреплено за одним маршрутом. Можно ли создать отдельную таблицу vehicle_route (id, v_id, r_id), так чтобы id - AUTO_INCREMNT PRIMARY KEY, а ввести запись с уже существующим v_id было невозможно? Вариант с связыванием маршрута в таблице vehicle по route_id не подходит, нужна отдельная таблица (в будущем хочу создать таблицу в которой будут прописани связи между driver  и  vehicle_route).

Comment: Используй `unique key`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, напишите пожалуйста примердля данного случая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26e922

```
create table tbl (
  a int not null primary key auto_increment,
  b int not null unique,
  c int not null
);

insert into tbl(b, c) values (7, 9);
insert into tbl(b, c) values (16, 3);
insert into tbl(b, c) values (78, 42);
```

Если добавить

```
insert into tbl(b, c) values (7, 101);
```

то получится ошибка:

> Duplicate entry '7' for key 'b'

Comment: Гениально, спасибо Вы мне очень помогли

Comment: ещетакой вопрос. Если уменя есть таблица справочник с одним полем, например, таблица marks (id) - марка авто с полем возможных марок. Они не повторяются и уникальны. id должен быть только - PK, если предпологается  использовать id в другой таблице как внешний ключ, ведь просто unique - не даст такой возможности, а PK - сам по себе уникален?

Comment: @MuscledBoy, unique и foreign key могут использоваться одновременно на одном столбце, разве нет?

Comment: вернее primary key и unique, возможен одновременно?

Comment: primary сам по себе уникален.

Comment: вот это меня и интересовало, спасибо